# Is perplexity in SRILM normalized for sentence length?

Tags: computational-linguistics, nlp, n-grams, language-models, evaluation-metrics

If I generate a language model with [SRILM](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/)'s ngram-count and then use `ngram -unk -ppl text -lm model` to get log probabilities and perplexity values, are the perplexities normalized for sentence length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it is not too late.

Both ppl and ppl1 are normalized according http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/srilm-faq.7.html
, which is called [entropy rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate).

Comment: @L3viathan Please post the answer when you find it...